# Setting noindex nofollow in a category page of Magento site

Tags: magento, frontend, seo, e-commerce, noindex

With the observer class below, I'm trying to set noindex and nofollow on a category page. I'm unable to get the code to first check if it is a category page and then set noindex if the title of the category page has "parts" in the category name. Can you please help find this out.

```
<?php

namespace Perfectmakeupmirrors\PmmHead\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class SetRobotsMetaTag implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $request;
    protected $registry;
    protected $layoutFactory;
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config $layoutFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger)

    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->layoutFactory = $layoutFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $this->logger->debug("Observer is watching");
        $this->logger->debug("Action Name = " . $this->request->getActionName());
        $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
        if ($this->request->getActionName() == 'category') { 
            $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
            $categoryName = $category->getName();
            $this->logger->debug("Category Name = $categoryName");
            if (stripos($categoryName, 'part') !== false) { 
                $this->logger->debug("Robots Set");
                $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure your objserver is called.

Comment: Yes, it is being called as I already verified with the logger statements that you can see in the execute method.

Comment: Did you get "Robots Set" in your log.

Comment: above code will do for your all category.

You should set  $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('INDEX,FOLLOW') in outer.

Comment: I was just testing the code when it was not setting noindex on the particular category page.

Comment: No, I did not get "Robots Set" in your log. Please have a look at that code

Comment: Did you get Category Name in logger?

Comment: Yes, it said View.

Comment: View is your category?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244776/discussion-between-codeforgood-and-s-p).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your function condition.

```
 public function execute(Observer $observer) {
    $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
    $categoryName = $category->getName();
    $categoryName = trim($categoryName);
    $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('INDEX,FOLLOW');
    if (stripos($categoryName, 'Parts') !== false) {
      $this->layoutFactory->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
    }
}
```